# How to resolve SEHException with COM Component?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, teigha

This is my environment.

C# / Winform / VisualStudio2013 / C++ dll(TeighaX)

We updated from TeighaX version 4 to 4.3.

**It works in other environment but not in my environment.**

An error message is generated when initializing form.

Error code is here.

```
System.Runtime.interopServices.SEHException(0x80004005):External component has thrown an exception.
```

I know it's an error message that is not mapped to .NET.

So I tried this.

1. change the x86
2. reinstall TeighaX 4.3
3. change the dll
   (AxInterop.Teighax, AxInterop.VIEWXLib, TeighaX, VIEWXLib it's all 4.3v)

but did'nt worked.

I'm thinking of debugging as the last way, but I only have a dll.

I want to use TeighaX 4.3.

Have any ideas?

Comment: Does it compile in your environment? Have you checked if it's correctly finding it on the solution's references?

Comment: Compile error has occurred, but the reference path seems to be fine. So I don't know what the problem...

Comment: any yellow icon on the references? Just as a test, try removing the reference to the .dll and readding it.

Comment: The yellow icon is not exist. But I tried again and did'nt work.

Comment: An ActiveX component is not allowed to throw exceptions.  All runtime errors must produce an error code, the CLR then turns it into a diagnosable managed exception.  If it does anyway then the CLR still catches it, but turns it into an SEHException.  This is almost always very, very nasty, an unhandled C++ exception for example.  You might be able to see more in the Output window if you enable unmanaged debugging.  Little else you can do about debugging it without source.  You'll have to assume that the way you are using the library is tripping the exception.  Or a bug in the update.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you for your answer. I will check how I use library and contact the company that provides dll.

Comment: Hi @H.seongjun do we have exact cause and answer for your question, I also facing same issue , Intermitting issue